# Where is brew supposed to put its link to its Python binary?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I recently tried to upgrade my Python version via brew and now I am stuck with OSX's system Python because Brew does not seem to be creating a link to it's Python binary.

`brew link python` outputs (yes I've tried relinking):

> Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5
>
> To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python

`brew --prefix` outputs:

```
/usr/local
```

And yet `ls /usr/local/python` outputs:

> ls: /usr/local/python: No such file or directory

Am I misunderstanding how brew is supposed to be working? Shouldn't it be putting a link to a python binary in my `/usr/local/bin` directory?

Comment: My python3 is in /usr/local/bin. 2.7 is in usr/bin. Pretty sure I installed using brew. Probably had to sudo when I did.

Comment: Have you tried running `brew doctor`? Maybe some of its warnings may help in resolving this issue.